# How to do class/label assignment from network in Accord.net SOM(Kohonen's)

Tags: c#, accord.net, self-organizing-maps

Could anybody tell how to get/assign cluster class/label from trained network.

Here is code example to give you an idea how I execute it:

```
Accord.Math.Random.Generator.Seed = 0;

int numberOfInputs = 3;
int hiddenNeurons = 25;

double[][] input =
{
     new double[] { -1, -1, -1 },
     new double[] { -1,  1, -1 },
     new double[] {  1, -1, -1 },
     new double[] {  1,  1, -1 },
     new double[] { -1, -1,  1 },
     new double[] { -1,  1,  1 },
     new double[] {  1, -1,  1 },
     new double[] {  1,  1,  1 },
     // ...
};

var network = new DistanceNetwork(numberOfInputs, hiddenNeurons);
var teacher = new SOMLearning(network);
double error = double.PositiveInfinity;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    error = teacher.RunEpoch(input);

// how can I know/assign class/label of each item in input array?
```

Answer (score 0):

The Accord samples may be further help:

[Clustering (SOM)](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/master/Samples/Neuro/Clustering%20(SOM)/MainForm.cs)

Particularly this section:

```
for (int y = 0, i = 0; y < 100; y++)
{
    // for all pixels
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++, i++, ptr += 6)
    {
        Neuron neuron = layer.Neurons[i];

        // red
        ptr[2] = ptr[2 + 3] = ptr[2 + stride] = ptr[2 + 3 + stride] =
            (byte)Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, neuron.Weights[0]));

        // green
        ptr[1] = ptr[1 + 3] = ptr[1 + stride] = ptr[1 + 3 + stride] =
            (byte)Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, neuron.Weights[1]));

        // blue
        ptr[0] = ptr[0 + 3] = ptr[0 + stride] = ptr[0 + 3 + stride] =
            (byte)Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, neuron.Weights[2]));
    }

    ptr += offset;
    ptr += stride;
}
```